# react-native - Images not rendering on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I’m rendering about 70 images on one screen in different components using ListItem from react-native-elements but the images don’t show up on Android, however, they render fine on iOS). I know that memory is handled differently on Android, so I changed all images to a 1kb tester image which fixed the issue. Right now, I’ve been able to compress my images to ~20kb each on average but they still don’t display on Android. I’m not sure I’ll be able to compress lower than that, so I was hoping to change my code or gain some insight here.

Code is below. Just to reiterate – this renders w/o an issue on iOS.

```js
_renderContent = () =>
    this.props.dressing.map(top => {
      const { checkboxes } = this.state;
      return (
        <ListItem
          key={top.id}
          avatar={
            <Image
              source={{ uri: top.url }}
              style={styles.listitemimage}
              resizeMode="contain"
            />
          }
          subtitle={
            <CheckBox
              title={
                checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(top.id)
                  ? 'Added'
                  : 'Click to Add'
              }
              onPress={() => {
                this.handlePress(top);
              }}
              checked={checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(top.id) ? true : false}
            />
          }
          chevronColor="white"
        />
      );
    });
```

I’m mapping through json data which holds the image url.

Example url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyrHT.jpg 1

I'm using Expo if that matters.

Comment: Try using a `FlatList` instead for better performance. Expo sometimes bugs out when you use too much memory

Comment: thanks, that's probably the issue. ill try it out

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it was just a performance issue.